# How to remove Designer tools 1.6 moduls from orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I install designer tools modules on orchard 1.7 . but after installation it give me the following Error :
1. Install any dependent module. 
2. Remove the assembly reference from the project file if it's not needed. 
3. Ensure the assembly reference is present in the 'bin' directory of the module. 
4. Ensure the assembly reference is present in the 'bin' directory of the application. 
5. Specify the strong name of the assembly (name, version, culture, publickey) if the assembly is present in the GAC.
not I need help how to resolve this problem .
or learn me how can I remove this modules from the command line ?
what's that I must enter in orchard command line to remove this modules ?
thanks 
Regards :
Raha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably installed the wrong version of the module. You actually didn't have to install anything as it comes standard with Orchard. Delete Modules/Orchard.DesignerTools and copy it back from the original distribution of Orchard that you used.